# Why I can't find inverse of matrix 2x2 by 3x3 method?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I was trying to find 2x2 matrix inverse by folllowing [3x3 matrix inverse tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvjkPF6C_LI). I had understood 3x3 matrix inverse but I couldn't use 3x3 system in 2x2.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}7 & 2 \\ 17 & 5\end{bmatrix}$$

It's the given matrix. So I am going to find det of it.

$$|A|=\det A=1$$

$$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{1}\begin{bmatrix}+|5| & -|17| \\ +|2| &-|7|\end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}5 & -17 \\ 2 & -7\end{bmatrix}$$

I thought it was correct answer. So I was trying to check validity by multiplying A and $A^{-1}$ after multiplying them I noticed my answer was incorrect. What I missed here? I had rechecked my work either but couldn't find any mistake. I was just following [his hiding variable method (I have added the accurate time)](https://youtu.be/YvjkPF6C_LI?t=153). From [the following equation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiBgjz5xbyg) I found that his method isn't helpful for 2x2 matrix. Or I understood his method wrong for 2x2 matrix.

[image]

Comment: Double check the signs in your solution. I think you missed the chess board rule for signs.

Comment: @istiakShovon Apart from a problem with signs, you need to consider the *transpose* of the cofactor matrix (some times called adjugate matrix), not the cofactors matrix itself.

Comment: @PierreCarre Oops! Ohh Yes! I wasn't familiar with these names. That's why I didn't reply. After watching video on Adjugate matrix I remember [the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvjkPF6C_LI) again.. I had missed something..